# server reset when accessing OWA externally

Tags: windows, outlook-web-app, reset

Just the other day I started having problems remote accessing email via OWA.

I get server reset or page cannot be displayed.  But the web page works fine. If I tried this over and over eventually I am able to login BUT if I am not quick it will error out when I am sending an email or refreshing giving the same error. BUT if I access OWN on the internet network there is no problem at all and it works 100 percent of the time with no errors.

The problem comes about accessing externally. I have a Netgear firewall only directing ports for OWA, http, https, and mail. Server receives mail with no problem from the outside.

**Summary:**

- Remote access to OWA is intermittent.
- On the internal network works 100 percent
- Error external is server reset connection
- Nothing has changed in the configuration and this only started happening a few days back.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Exchange? Which OS?